# Mockito when...thenResult always returns null

Tags: java, mockito

With the above code I always get an error in line of test

```
when(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory"))
    .thenReturn(factory);
```

Any ideas?

*Java class*

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory");
        ...............
}
```

*Test class*

```
 @Test
    public void testServlet() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);       
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);    


        factory = contextInitialized();
       when(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory")).thenReturn(factory); //Always error here
        when(request.getParameter("empId")).thenReturn("35");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("somefile.txt");
        when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

       new DeleteEmployee().doGet(request, response);

        verify(request, atLeast(1)).getParameter("username"); // only if you want to verify username was called...
        writer.flush(); // it may not have been flushed yet...
        assertTrue(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("somefile.txt"), "UTF-8")
                   .contains("My Expected String"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
when(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory")).thenReturn(factory);
```

This bit:

```
request.getServletContext().getAttribute("SessionFactory")
```

is a chained call; you're trying to stub both the request, and the servlet context that the request returns.

You can do that, but you need to use [deep stubs](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.3/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

```
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Comment: @carloshernando accept the answer if you find it correct

Comment: @JeanValjean This is how I got my "unsung hero" badge. Still proud of that one. It does also stop other people wasting time coming to answer too, thanks.