# Mockito when…thenResult always returns null Part 2

Tags: java, rest, mockito

After resolve mi first mockito issue, i found my second one(very similar to my first one, but i don't know how to fix it)

I have this rest java function:

```
@GET
@Path("/deleteEmployee")
@Produces("application/json")
public ReturnCode  deleteEmployee(@QueryParam("empId") String empIdToDelete)
{
    ReturnCode returnCode = new ReturnCode(Constants.NO_ERROR_CODE, Constants.NO_ERROR_TEXT);
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context.getAttribute("SessionFactory");
```

and this test:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteServlet() throws Exception {
    ServletContext context =  mock (ServletContext.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    SessionFactory factory = contextInitialized();  

    when(context.getAttribute("SessionFactory")).thenReturn(factory);
    new EmployeeOps().deleteEmployee("33");    
}
```

Why always crashes with null pointer in SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context.getAttribute("SessionFactory");?

[Other mockito issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623142/mockito-when-thenresult-always-returns-null)

Comment: `context` is `null`. The `context` in `testDeleteServlet` is different from the field in `deleteEmployee`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: It seems,And how must be fixed?And why it worked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623142/mockito-when-thenresult-always-returns-null

Comment: Pass the mock `ServletContext` to your `EmployeeOps` object.

Comment: Are you injecting/passing your mock to tested controler?

Comment: i didn't watch it before, but yes. it is defined as     @Context ServletContext context;

Comment: And what do you think processes that `context`? Why shouldn't it be `null`? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I have changed the java app adding the method

```
protected void setContext(ServletContext context)
    {
        this.context= context;
    }
```

and i have changed the test with:

```
 @Override
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        context =  mock (ServletContext.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        employeeOps = new EmployeeOps();
        employeeOps.setContext(context);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteServlet() throws Exception {

        SessionFactory factory = contextInitialized();
        when(context.getAttribute("SessionFactory")).thenReturn(factory);
        employeeOps.deleteEmployee("41");

    }
```

With this it works fine.
Thanks everyone!